# how to change the popup title in java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, push-notification, notifications, service-worker

could you  please tell me how to change the pop up **title** ..currently it is showing  `http:\\s.codepen.io` can we change this url ?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WRaZOq

```
function notifyMe() {
  // Let's check if the browser supports notifications
  if (!("Notification" in window)) {
    alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
  }

  // Let's check whether notification permissions have already been granted
  else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    // If it's okay let's create a notification
    var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
  }

  // Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
  else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
    Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
      // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
      if (permission === "granted") {
        var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
      }
    });
  }

  // At last, if the user has denied notifications, and you 
  // want to be respectful there is no need to bother them any more.
}Notification.requestPermission().then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});function spawnNotification(theBody,theIcon,theTitle) {
  var options = {
      icon: theIcon
  }
  var n = new Notification(theTitle,options);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a look at the Notification [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/Notification)

First arg. is the *title* and the second arg. is an object specifying other details including *body* of the message.So you need something like this

```
var notification = new Notification("the title",{body:"body of the notification"});
```